# PHP - Adding up an array of numbers?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that returns an array of numbers:

```
$fh = fopen ("./files/".$file, r);
$filedata= explode('|', fgets($fh));

  echo $filedata[5];
```

result:

0.23387718200684

3.6163940429688

0.030826568603516

Is there a way to get the script to return results added up as just one number?

Comment: What gets printed when you do `var_dump($filedata[5])`? Note that neither `fopen` nor `explode` automatically adds numbers.

Comment: @NullUserException: `explode()` always returns an array of strings, so it's definitely a string...

Comment: Could You show us the file with input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your code, you are executing it in command line and you do echo $filedata[5] an you get different lines, this is because you are not paying attention to '\n' character, so what you need is to change that character somehow...
there are different ways... In this example I'm changing the "\n" for " " simple space

```
$fh = fopen ("./files/".$file, r);
$filedata= explode('|', fgets($fh));

// if "\n" is not working try '\n'

// One way
echo str_replace(" ","\n",$filedata[5]);

// Another way
echo implode(" ", explode("\n", $filedata[5]));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo array_sum($filedata);
```

I think that should do the trick.

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) for further information.  array_sum just sums up all the values in an array.

*EDIT*
The above example would work if your array was a flat array of integers, decimals etc.  The following is how you would sum up a 2 dimensional array where the value you want to sum is at index position 5:

```
var $sum = 0;

foreach($filedata as $dataElement) {
    $sum += $dataElement[5];
}

echo $sum;
```

The above code assume that $filedata is an array of array's, each array in filedata has a value at index 5 that can be summed up... Is that more along the lines of what you need?

Comment: No, because the number is in $filedata[5]. You'll need a loop to sum up only the `5` indexes of the returned explode arrays.

Comment: OK - in which case you'll need a foreach - loop through the array and sum up all values in $filedata[5].  Either that or you could create an array of all the values in $filedata position [5] and then sum those up with the above example.

Comment: Ya array_sum dosen't return anything :(

Comment: This could be solved in such a nice way in python... `sum(x.split('|')[5] for x in f)` with `f` being the file object - too bad PHP lacks the features needed for this :)

Comment: :( so I cannot do this in PHP?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yup. Or ES6: `filedata.pluck(x -> x[5]).reduce((a, b) -> a + b)` or VB.NET: `filedata.Select(Function(x) x(5)).Sum()` I suppose PHP *does* have `array_map` though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668164/collecting-column-values-into-an-array

Comment: @Marc:  That isn't necessarily true.  The OP only echos the 5th index, but says the array is an array if numbers.  He isn't very clear on what he has/wants, but if `$filedata` is an array of numbers and he wants the sum of all of its values, this will work just fine.  If this code is in a loop, and he's trying to sum the 5th value of each array, however, you'd be correct.

Comment: @minitech: `->` is actually available in ES6? Looks more like this ugly languaged called CoffeeScript to me

Comment: Just a quick one - scratch my answer and look at @Wesley van Opdorp's - mine's a bit of a hack and his looks more complete.  Good luck!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yes, yes it is. If you prefer it could be `function(a, b) a + b` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could use array_sum:

```
echo array_sum($filedata);
```

**Not working?**

As might be your case `$filedata[5]` actually contains a string with newlines and numbers. In this case you need some extra code. Important is the line endings - these can be different depending on your operating system / file.

```
$sum = 0;
$sLineEnding = "\r\n";
foreach($filedata as $data)
{
    $parts = explode($sLineEnding, $data);
    $sum += array_sum($parts);
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: that still returns 4 lines of numbers